# Block all IP addresses unless specified

Tags: configuration, gitlab

I want to block all IP-addresses trying to connect to my omnibus server but I can't seem to find a setting for this in the gitlab.rb config file.

I've found the nginx config file but there is a notice that any changes will be overwritten, which seems as a bit risky if a reconfiguration is triggered and I forget to add the IP-blocking afterwards.

How do I block/redirect all IP-addresses but my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as the way to do this is to setup entries in the iptables, blocking all connections but the given ip addresses.